# Hiding Divs with a class except one with a specifick ID using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a blog page to showcase some of my projects. Each project is inside a div with a common class but all have different ID's, the first project is id="blog-post1", the second project is id="blog-post2" and so on. On the right side of the page I have buttons which will show you only one of the projects to read through and hide the other, it works just fine, see code below:

```
function hideshow(btn) {
    var a = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="blog-post"]');
    var b = document.getElementById(btn);
    a.forEach(a => {
      a.style.display = "none";
    })

    b.style.display = "block";
  }

  function showall() {
    var a = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="blog-post"]');
    a.forEach(a => {
      a.style.display = "block";
    })
  }
```

The above works fine but it seems like it is not a very elegant solution (I'm very new to this). First I hide all Divs and then change the display status of the Div I need back again to "block". Is there perhaps a way to do a querySelectAll for all ID's that start with "blog-post" but except the one the viewer clicked on (given by the btn selector)?.

Comment: There is also a Code Review site from SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding a check in the loop not to hide the div you want.

```
a.forEach(a => {
  if (a.id != btn) a.style.display = "none";
})
```

Comment: ```function hideshow(btn)
var a = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="blog-post"]:not(btn)');
a.forEach(a => {
if (a.id == btn) a.style.display = "block";
if (a.id != btn) a.style.display = "none";
})
}```

This works flawlessly, thank you